# How do I distrust an Apt key in Debian Linux?

Tags: debian, apt, gpg

How do I distrust an *Apt* key in *Debian Linux*, or prevent one from being silently added via `apt-key` (like most commercial packages tend to do in their `postinst` scripts)?

If I run `apt-key adv --edit-key ... trust`, it doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
# apt-key adv --edit-key D38B4796 trust
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.poumWAEgYJ/gpg.1.sh --edit-key D38B4796 trust
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.18; Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.


pub  rsa4096/7721F63BD38B4796
     created: 2016-04-12  expires: never       usage: SC  
sub  rsa4096/1397BC53640DB551
     created: 2016-04-12  expires: 2019-04-12  usage: S   
sub  rsa4096/6494C6D6997C215E
     created: 2017-01-24  expires: 2020-01-24  usage: S   
[ unknown] (1). Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>

pub  rsa4096/7721F63BD38B4796
     created: 2016-04-12  expires: never       usage: SC  
sub  rsa4096/1397BC53640DB551
     created: 2016-04-12  expires: 2019-04-12  usage: S   
sub  rsa4096/6494C6D6997C215E
     created: 2017-01-24  expires: 2020-01-24  usage: S   
[ unknown] (1). Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>

Please decide how far you trust this user to correctly verify other users' keys
(by looking at passports, checking fingerprints from different sources, etc.)

  1 = I don't know or won't say
  2 = I do NOT trust
  3 = I trust marginally
  4 = I trust fully
  5 = I trust ultimately
  m = back to the main menu

Your decision? 2

pub  rsa4096/7721F63BD38B4796
     created: 2016-04-12  expires: never       usage: SC  
sub  rsa4096/1397BC53640DB551
     created: 2016-04-12  expires: 2019-04-12  usage: S   
sub  rsa4096/6494C6D6997C215E
     created: 2017-01-24  expires: 2020-01-24  usage: S   
[ unknown] (1). Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
Please note that the shown key validity is not necessarily correct
unless you restart the program.

gpg>
```

-- so when I re-run `apt-key list`, the trust level is still `unknown`:

```
# apt-key list D38B4796
pub   rsa4096 2016-04-12 [SC]
      EB4C 1BFD 4F04 2F6D DDCC  EC91 7721 F63B D38B 4796
uid           [ unknown] Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
sub   rsa4096 2016-04-12 [S] [expires: 2019-04-12]
sub   rsa4096 2017-01-24 [S] [expires: 2020-01-24]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I’m aware, the trust settings on keys don’t have any effect on `apt`. Trust in this context refers to the value given to signatures *of other keys* made with a given key; it’s about transitive trust in the web of trust, not trust in the validity of package signatures (or rather, repository signatures) made with a given key.

To “distrust” a repository key you need to delete it.

To prevent packages installing new keyrings, you can add a file to `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/`, called for example `no-new-keyrings`, containing

```
# Skip installation of new keyrings by default, but allow Debian keyrings
path-exclude=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/*
path-include=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-*
```

This won’t prevent packages installing keys using `apt-key`; to do that would probably involve writing a wrapper.